# K8S service load balancer annotation for sg source ips

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb, kops

I have k8s cluster deployed over aws.
I created load balancer service with annotation of : 
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
now, I saw that k8s created new elb attached to a sg with outbound role 443 opened to 0.0.0.0/0.
I tried to take a look and see if there's additional annotation that manage source ip's (pre defined ip's instead the 0.0.0.0) and couldn't find.
Do you know if there's kind of option to manage this as part of annotations ?

Comment: which ingress are you using? nginx-ingress?

Comment: Generally yes, but in this case i'm not using ingress but ext loadbalancer

Comment: @RoeeRakovsky loadBalancerSourceRanges works on aws and gcloud

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `loadBalancerSourceRanges` in loadbalancer service resource as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-cloud-provider-firewall/#restrict-access-for-loadbalancer-service).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8765
    targetPort: 9376
  selector:
    app: example
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 10.0.0.0/8
```

**Update:**

In case of nginx-ingress you can use `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range` annotation.

For more info check [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#whitelist-source-range).